# Make this function work with prepare

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have seen this function online to bring a basic support for named parameters for MySQli:

```
function parseNamedParams(&$queryStr, &$params)
{
    $array = array();
    if ($c = preg_match_all('/(:\w+)/is', $queryStr, $matches)) { // To match words starting with colon
        $list = $matches[0]; // $matches is two-dimensional array, we only need first element
        foreach($list as $value) { // We'll replace each parameter in the query string with a '?' (as to comply with mysqli), and make sure the value is in the correct order.
            $queryStr = str_replace($value, '?', $queryStr);
            $array[] = $params[$value];
        }
        $params = $array;
    }
}
```

I've been trying to use it:

```
$DB = new mysqli("host","user","pass","db");
$Query = "SELECT uname FROM test WHERE uname = :user";
$Params = array (
":user" => "Sophie"
);
$Bind = parseNamedParams($Query, $Params);

$SQL = $DB->prepare($Bind);
$SQL->execute();
$SQL->bind_result($Username);
$SQL->fetch();
$SQL->close();
```

But alas, this does not work

**Update**
*Forgot to include the error message:*

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 25

Comment: You're not returning anything from your bindNamedParams function, so `$Bind` is null.

Comment: @andrewsi How would one modify this function for a sucesfull return?

Comment: @andrewsi - the parameters to the function are passed by reference so the function operates directly on the source variables. There's no need for a return value.

Comment: You don't need to return anything from the function - it's directly modifying the parameters you're passing in.

Comment: @andrewsi Then where am I going wrong?

Comment: @MikeW - you are quite correct. But she's assigning the non-existant return value to `$Bind`, and then using that in `prepare()`.

Comment: @SophieMackeral - after this function is called, you'll have your updated SQL query in `$Query`, and the parameters in `$Params`. You need to prepare the statement, and bind the parameters, and it should work.

Comment: @andrewsi after doing `echo $Query;` I get: `SELECT uname FROM test WHERE uname = '?'`, so it's a little bit redundant

Comment: @andrewsi If you can show me how this is done completely, i'll start a bounty with +100, because it's really bugging me that Ican't get it working even with the knowledge that i've already received

Comment: Sorry, what's a little bit redundant?

Comment: Actually, this function should return already prepared and executed statement

Answer (score -1):

If your looking for PDO Style prepared statements, then switch to PDO... But if you really insist on doing this, then I have the following solution:

```
function Named_Params ($Query, $Params,$DBLink){
    $New_Param = array_values($Params);
    $Count = 0;
    if (preg_match_all('/(:\w+)/is',$Query,$Match)){
        $List = $Match[0];
        foreach ($List AS $Value){
            $Secure_Var = $DBLink->real_escape_string($New_Param[$Count]);
           $Query = str_replace($Value,$Secure_Var, $Query);
            $Count++;
        }
    }
    return $Query;
}
$DB = new mysqli("","","","");
$Query = "SELECT uname FROM test WHERE uname = ':user'";
$Params = array (
    ":user" => "Sophie"
);
$Input = Named_Params($Query,$Params,$DB);

$Query = $DB->prepare($Input);
$Query->execute();
$Query->bind_result($Username);
$Query->fetch();
$Query->close();
    echo $Name;
```

Hopefully this is what your looking for

Comment: Is it written in editor and then debugged and run or just written right off your head in place?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Written using a well known PHP IDE - PHPStorm, runs without error on PHP5.4/5.5, though I should spend a couple of minutes cleaning up the un-used variables, but it works as is

Comment: I see now. This approach is flawed, because it doesn't use prepared statements.

Comment: @YourCommonSense PHP  has it's own flaws which stuff that shouldn't work.. Does work, I believe that it's working because it's just changing the `:user` with the param passed into the `str_replace`, so therefore. the query is: `SELECT uname FROM test WHERE uname='Sophie'` which is searching the database and working with a true bool return

Comment: @YourCommonSense Maybe so, but i've input some type of database security by using escaped strings, maybe not 100%. At the end of it, it's doing what the OP wishes.. Perhaps she can see whats actually going on and how I agree you that this method is flawed

Comment: The OP definitely wishes to use **native prepared statements.**

Comment: @YourCommonSense This is the only way I see it possible to use such a method, nethertheless, still confused why the downvote for something that is doing what is required

Comment: **The OP definitely wishes to use native prepared statements.** <-- this is what actually required and where you **failed.** You need to learn what prepared statement is and how to use it first.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Your free to post your own answer getting what's needed done